# using more than one managed bean in same jsf page

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

If I have page, lets say includes two different customers informations, how can I use two different managed beans (which is same java class) in the same page?

As a summary, in the same page I want to hold information of one customer in one bean, another in another bean.

Comment: Why are you asking a rhetorical question? How exactly did it fail when you try/do it anyway?

Comment: I dont understand this "I use two different managed beans (which is same java class)" If I understand it well just use #{someBean.someproperty} and #{anotherBean.someproperty}

Comment: I mean when it requires someBean and anotherBean is the same java class:

#{someBean.someproperty} and #{anotherBean.someproperty}

Answer (score 0):

> I want to hold information of one customer in one bean, another in
>   another bean.

Another bean for same purpose is duplication, and If you are thinking it logical. Every page have its page's state (life). when you try `#{bean.customer}` it will return same value. Because its object is same.

I would suggest to improve your code use another class for the view, layer your application. like

```
//Base class
    public class Customer {
    private String id;
    /*
     *Other fields
     */

    //getter Setters
    }

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PageBackingBean implements Serializable{
    List<Customer> customer = new ArrayList<>(); //can Hold more than one customer

    public PageBackingBean(){
           Customer cus1 = DataBase.loadByCustomerId(id);
           customer.add(cus1);

           Customer cus2 = DataBase.loadByCustomerId(id);
           customer.add(cus2);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer as you said better to seperate them. I just didnt want to create two quite similar classes.

Comment: Until it saves the life, page's backing have a scope and bean have its life accordingly. Page's all backings can store exactly 1 record, e.g. in hibernate Pojo class == database's 1 record. When you traverse it looses pervious one.